# how to implement gridview inside carouselslider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

attached image for reference [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xsl7.png)

i am new to flutter looking for suggestions. Can anybody suggest how can i achieve this kind of design in flutter. Any suggestions would be appreciated.I think i need to implement grid view inside CarouselSlider.
any codesnippets for this design would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```html
Column(
            children: [
 Container(
                      child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                      itemCount: {ur_array}.length,
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        autoPlay: true,
                        aspectRatio: 4.0,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index, i) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
               
                          },
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                      {imageurlyouwanttoshow},
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      width: 1000)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )),
              Flexible(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 6.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 6.0),
                  itemCount: controller.datas.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return InkWell(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        child: ImageCacheing(url: controller.datas[i].imgurl!),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) library? If so, here's an example:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: CarouselSlider(
        options: CarouselOptions(
          viewportFraction: 1,
          height: 300,
        ),
        items: [
          GridView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              mainAxisSpacing: 5,
              crossAxisSpacing: 5,
            ),
            children: List.generate(
              6,
              (index) => Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('Item $index'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```